Trying to add stacking in a RNG inventory
Me and some friends are creating a RNG game (We are very new) and don't know a way to make the items you've collected stack.
When you collect a duplicate of an item it will show up twice in your inventory
enter image description here
Anybody know a way to fix this?

It's not clear which programming language you're using. In general, the solution is either object-oriented programming where you'd create an object holding the rarity of the object and its count. Or you can use some kind of a data structure, possibly a "bag" (also known as "multiset"). But first get accustomed to hashmaps (or "dictionaries", depending on your language), hashsets, and how data structures using hashing work in your language.
In short, data structures. If you've gone through arrays and lists, look at sets and maps, then jump to multisets or build your own which fits your purpose

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When posting, always show the code you have, what you've tried, the full errors that you are getting (where applicable) and, especially in this case, the desired outcome. If you're not tagging a programming language then 90 out of 100 you're doing something wrong.
